# What will happen if the most influential individual stake-holder STOP responding?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm new to the community and I'm trying to do some research for my college project with respect to the Ethereum topic.

I'm curious how influential the highest stake-holder would be. From my understanding, there are two cases:

1. Some individual has a very large portion of the current stake (say, 30% of the overall ETH? Just a thought experiment). She didn't choose to deposit any of her asset to become a validator. Then, if someday she lost her wallet, how will the community be affected? Nothing?
2. Some individual has a very large portion of the current stake. She used all her ETH to be multiple validators. Suppose she is using only one machine, and sadly someday the machine stopped working forever. What will happen to the community?

I know those thought experiments are unrealistic, but from my standpoint I'm just wondering if there exists some supernode, what will be the influence if it disappear suddenly. Any explanation will be appreciated! Thanks.